# Unmarshal JSON to Struct of Map

Tags: json, dictionary, go, struct, unmarshalling

I have below program. I need to convert JSON data into object type cache which contains a single field of map[string]string type. There is something that I am doing wrong w.r.t. initialising map and unmarshalling JSON but unable to identify the syntax issue.

Note: I have marshalled data just for convenience sake to have sample JSON data.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "strconv"
)

const data = `{"Mode":{"ID-1":"ON","ID-2":"OFF","ID-3":"ON"}}`

type Cache struct {
    Mode map[string]string `json:"Mode"`
}

func main() {
    jsonData, _ := json.Marshal(data)
    fmt.Println(strconv.Unquote(string(jsonData)))

    var c Cache
    c.Mode = make(map[string]string) //I want to initialise map so that I can store data in next step, but this is wrong I know
    c.Mode["ID-4"] = "ON" //Want to store data like this
    
    json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &c) 
    fmt.Println(c) //I am getting output as nil map i.e. {map[]}
    for k, v := range c.Mode {
        fmt.Println(k, v) //I am getting NO output i.e. blank
    }
}
```

Comment: You are unmarshaling a json-encoded string. Simply unmarshal the json input: `json.Unmarshal([]byte(data),&c)`

Comment: The error returned from json.Unmarshal explains the problem.  Always check errors.  Fix by decoding the original JSON document instead of a JSON encoding of the string containing the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your your code fixed https://play.golang.org/p/5ftaiz_Q5wl (attaching blow the copy)

```
package main
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

const data = `{"Mode":{"ID-1":"ON","ID-2":"OFF","ID-3":"ON"}}`

type Cache struct {
    Mode map[string]string `json:"Mode"`
}

func main() {
    c := Cache{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &c)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    c.Mode["ID-4"] = "ON" //Want to store data like this

    fmt.Println(c) 
    for k, v := range c.Mode {
        fmt.Println(k, v) 
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
{map[ID-1:ON ID-2:OFF ID-3:ON ID-4:ON]}
ID-2 OFF
ID-3 ON
ID-4 ON
ID-1 ON
```